# Prove that $\mathbb{Z} ( p^\infty) \cap \mathbb{Z} ( q^\infty) = (\overline{0})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $ G=\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. Let $p$ be a prime integer and $\bar{<\frac{1}{p^n}>} $ is the subgroup generated by $\bar{\frac{1}{p^n}}$. Let $\mathbb{Z} ( p^\infty)= \bigcup_{p>0} \bar{<\frac{1}{p^n}>}$. Prove the following:
>
> If $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, then $\mathbb{Z} ( p^\infty) \cap \mathbb{Z} ( q^\infty) = (\overline{0})$.

Attempt:

Clearly, $\overline{0}\in \mathbb{Z} ( p^\infty) \cap \mathbb{Z} ( q^\infty)$ because $\overline{0}=\overline{\frac{p}{p}} =\overline{\frac{q}{q}}$.

So $(\overline{0}) \subset\mathbb{Z} ( p^\infty) \cap \mathbb{Z} ( q^\infty) $.

Now, suppose that $x\in \mathbb{Z} ( p^\infty) \cap \mathbb{Z} ( q^\infty)$. We want to show that $x \in \overline{(0)}$.

$x=\overline{\frac{a}{p^n}}= \overline{\frac{b}{q^m}}$ for some $n$ and $m$.

$\overline{\frac{a}{p^n}}- \overline{\frac{b}{q^m}}=\overline{0}$

$\overline{\frac{aq^m-bp^n}{p^n q^m}} =\overline{0}$

How can I complete this, please. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** without loss of generality, you can assume $p \not \mid a$ and $q \not \mid b$. Your last equality implies, however, that

$$
aq^m-bp^n = p^nq^m c \tag{$\star$}
$$

for some $c \in \mathbb Z$. What happens if both $n$ and $m$ are positive?

> First, let us prove the "without loss of generality" part. Write $a = p^k a'$ with $\mathbf{gcd}(p,a') = 1$. If $k > n$, then $a/p^n$ is an integer, its class is zero, and there is nothing to prove. Otherwise, we can write $a/p^n = a'/p^{n-k}$. Now, if $n,m \geq 1$ then $(\star)$ implies that $p \mid aq^m$, so $p\mid q^m$. Hence $p \mid q$, a contradiction. We see in this way that either $n = 0$ or $m = 0$. But then either $a/p^n \in \mathbb Z$ or $b/p^m \in \mathbb Z$, in either case their classes (which coincide) are the class of $0$.